# different variables training/test set with 'randomForest' package

Tags: r, random-forest

Let's say I have a classification problem, and want to use the randomForest package in R to solve this.

In my training set I want to add a *third* variable, **var3**, which is the product of var1 and var2. Thus, the training set would consist of
var1, var2, var3 and the class variable.

However, this **var3** is not present in the *test set*, and consequently, randomForest will give an error when I want to test my model:

```
random forest Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object var3 not found
```

Is there any way to get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the formula interface to build the product in the model specification:

```
    class_var ~ var1 + var2 + I(var1 * var2)
```

The `I` function means that the value of the product will be calculated rather than producing the result of `interaction` which is not the numerical product if either of the variables is character or factor (and is basically a no-op when they are both numeric). There can be problems with this: when the values of var1 and var2 are large, the errors around the estimates may dominate the calculation. I suppose it might be safer to run this:

```
  class_var ~ var1 + var2 + I( scale(var1 * var2) )
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks :) I played around with it and, if you want to pick a column this works as well: class_var ~ var1 + var2 + I(df$varx)

Comment: At what stage in the process? Seems like doing that when `df` was the expected evaluation frame would just make this more complicated. Could just use: `class_var ~ var1 + var2 + varx`

Comment: Thanks for the follow up! This was also in the training process. When I do what you suggest I get the error again (object varx not found), since this variable is not present in the test set. However, adding the interaction I don't get the error.

Comment: I'm not understanding but it sounds as though that doesn't matter, since you have an effective process.

Comment: Im probably explaining it wrong hehe. In this situation I assume that `varx` is some variable I want to use for training my randomforest model. But this variable is not included in the (separate) test set. Adding the interaction function seems to do the trick!